# JSON: Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead

Tags: json, swift

Heres the json response snippet:

```
 "hp": "130",
 "types": [
      "Lightning"
      ],...
```

Here's my Decodable model snippet:

```
struct Pokemon: Decodable {
    let hp: String?
    let types: [Types]?
}

struct Types: Decodable {
    let types: String
}
```

And the title of this post is the error Im getting. Ive tried all that I can but still cant fix the error.
Many thanks

Comment: This JSON maps to `let types: [String]` rather than to `[Types]`... `struct` types map to a JSON object, so for `[Types]` the JSON would need to be  `[{ "types": "something" }, ...]`

Comment: Yes you are right I have now mapped "types" to [String] and it works, thanks man. FYI I have included "snippet" into my question for clarity.